# Convex optimization with linear constraints. Can I solve it analytically?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization, duality, constrained-optimization

I have a constrained convex optimization problem with linear equality and inequality constraints.

\begin{align}
\label{eq:costf}
\text{minimize}\ \ 
    &f(x_1,\dots,x_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{x_i}\\
\text{so that}\ \ 
    &\sum_{i=1}^m x_i = ab\\ 
    &x_1 - c  \leq 0,\\
&-x_m + d  \leq 0,\\
&c+d-b \leq 0\ .
\end{align}
Note that $x_i>0,\ i=1,...,m$ and $x_1\leq...\leq x_m$. Also $a,b,c,d > 0$. Can this problem be solved analytically?

**CONSIDERATIONS:**
The Lagrangian and its gradient can be easily computed and set to zero
\begin{equation}
        \begin{cases}
         -\frac{1}{x_1^2} + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 +\nu &=0\\
         - \frac{1}{x_2^2} +\nu &=0\\
         &\vdots\\
         - \frac{1}{x_{m-1}^2} +\nu &=0\\
         - \frac{1}{x_m^2} -\lambda_{3}-\lambda_{4} +\nu &=0
        \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
and so the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions can be derived and used to find a solution. Solving the dual problem might be also a viable solution.

The fact that $x_1$ and $x_m$ are respectively the smallest and largest variable can be expressed by including $x_1 - \frac{ab}{m}  \leq 0$ and $-x_m + \frac{ab}{m} \leq 0$ among the inequality constraints.

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. Are $a,b,c,d$ all constants? If so, are they all positive/nonnegative, and do we know anything about the value of $a$ (is it related to $b,c,d$ in any way)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for welcoming me and for your interest as well. $a,b,c,d$ are all positive constants. $a$ is not related to the other constants and is $\geq1$. I'll edit

Comment: It is unlikely IMO but you can easily reformulate it as an SOCP. Also you are maximizing the harmonic mean which is the inverse of your objective.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK you mean that by reformulating as SOCP it's unlikely to find an analytic solution? Starting from an harmonic mean maximization would help in formulating the SOCP as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941021/maximizing-a-harmonic-mean). Is that why you pointed it out?

Comment: I'm not sure how $x_1\le \frac{ab}{m}$ implies that $x_1$ is the smallest variable etc.

Comment: I think you're right. $x_1$ being the smallest implies the condition $x_1\leq (ab)/m$. But the opposite is not true. However, as a sufficient condition, it should be included in the constraints, although a more strict condition would be better. Then how to embed "$x_1$ is the smallest" in the problem?

Comment: To embed "$x_1$ is the smallest", you add the constraints $x_1 \le x_j$ for every $j>1.$ However, if you want to enforce sort order, you just need $x_1 \le x_2,$ $x_2 \le x_3,$ etc.

Comment: My comment about the harmonic mean was meant as some potentially useful information. For instance if you minimize the arithmetic mean you will get an upper bound. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean. Also I meant you can use SOCP if you cannot find an analytical solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to be dealing with various cases depending on the values of $c,d,ab$ and $m.$ I think I can get you part way, but I have not dealt with all the cases.

Given that the objective function and the equation constraint treat
all variables $x_{i}$ identically, we can ignore the requirement
that $x_{1}\le x_{2}\dots\le x_{m}$ and just require that the smallest
(largest) variable be at most (at least) $c$ ($d$). Since permuting
a candidate solution does not affect the objective or constraint,
we can simplify this further to $x_{1}\le c$ and $x_{m}\ge d$, which
(assuming $x$ satisfies the equation constraint) are sufficient to
ensure that the sorted version of $x$ is feasible.

Let $[m]$ denote the index set $\left\{ 1,\dots,m\right\} .$ For
any $S\subseteq[m]$ and any $K>0$ let
$$
g(S,K)=\min\left\{ \sum_{i\in S}\frac{1}{x_{i}}:x>0,\sum_{i\in S}x_{i}=K\right\} .
$$
Using the convexity of the function $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, we can
show that the minimum occurs at $x_{i}=\frac{K}{\vert S\vert}\ \forall i$
with $g(S,K)=\frac{\vert S\vert^{2}}{K}.$ Thus, in the absence of
the requirements that $x_{1}\le c$ and $x_{m}\ge d$, the solution
to the original problem would be $\hat{x}=\left(\frac{ab}{m},\dots,\frac{ab}{m}\right)$
with value $g([m],ab)=\frac{m^{2}}{ab}.$

Now suppose that $x_{m}$ has been fixed at some value $h$ with $d\le h<ab.$
The best possible solution with $x_{m}=h$ is found by solving for
$g\left([m-1],ab-h\right).$ To avoid division by zero, we need the strict inequality $ab-h-x_{1}>0,$
which we will enforce as $x_{1}\le ab-h-\epsilon$ for some small
positive $\epsilon.$ We can express the reduced problem as
\begin{align*}
\min_{0<x_1\le\gamma} & \frac{1}{x_1}+g\left(\left\{ 2,\dots,m-1\right\} ,ab-h-x_1\right)\\
=\min_{0<x_1\le\gamma} & \frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{(m-2)^{2}}{ab-h-x_1}
\end{align*}
where $\gamma=\min(c,ab-h-\epsilon).$

In the absence of the requirement that $x_{1}\le c,$ we know from
convexity that the optimal solution would be $x_1=\frac{ab-h}{m-1},$
where the partial derivative w.r.t. $x_1$ changes from negative to
positive. So the optimal choice of $x_{1}$ is
$$
x_{1}=\begin{cases}
\frac{ab-h}{m-1} & \gamma\ge\frac{ab-h}{m-1}\\
\gamma & \gamma<\frac{ab-h}{m-1}
\end{cases}
$$
with corresponding objective values
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{(m-1)^{2}}{ab-h} & \gamma\ge\frac{ab-h}{m-1}\\
\frac{1}{\gamma}+\frac{(m-2)^{2}}{ab-h-\gamma} & \gamma<\frac{ab-h}{m-1}
\end{cases}.
$$
Now you just have to optimize that with respect to the value $h$ for $x_2$, taking into account the requirements that $h\ge d$ and $ab-h > 0.$